# MS SQL Server 2019 setup fails in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu

I tried to install the MS SQL Server 2019 and 2017 on the the latest Pop OS based on Ubuntu 22.04 but the setup fails every time with output:

```
⥂ sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup                                                                                                                                             10:04:52 PM
[sudo] password for s: 
Choose an edition of SQL Server:
  1) Evaluation (free, no production use rights, 180-day limit)
  2) Developer (free, no production use rights)
  3) Express (free)
  4) Web (PAID)
  5) Standard (PAID)
  6) Enterprise (PAID) - CPU Core utilization restricted to 20 physical/40 hyperthreaded
  7) Enterprise Core (PAID) - CPU Core utilization up to Operating System Maximum
  8) I bought a license through a retail sales channel and have a product key to enter.

Details about editions can be found at
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2109348&clcid=0x409

Use of PAID editions of this software requires separate licensing through a
Microsoft Volume Licensing program.
By choosing a PAID edition, you are verifying that you have the appropriate
number of licenses in place to install and run this software.

Enter your edition(1-8): 6
The license terms for this product can be found in
/usr/share/doc/mssql-server or downloaded from:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2104294&clcid=0x409

The privacy statement can be viewed at:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=853010&clcid=0x409

Enter the SQL Server system administrator password: 
Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password: 
The passwords do not match. Please try again.
Enter the SQL Server system administrator password: 
Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password: 
Configuring SQL Server...

This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Sat May  7 22:05:17 2022
The following diagnostic information is available:

         Reason: 0x00000001
         Signal: SIGSEGV - Segmentation fault (11)
          Stack:
                 IP               Function
                 ---------------- --------------------------------------
                 0000564990454abc <unknown>
                 0000564990454502 <unknown>
                 000056499046e786 <unknown>
                 00005649903f086b <unknown>
                 00007f1bf840c520 __sigaction+0x50
                 0000000000000000 <unknown>
                 0000564990410dce <unknown>
                 00005649903ecb14 <unknown>
                 00005649903ec939 <unknown>
        Process: 18822 - sqlservr
         Thread: 18958 (application thread 0x23c)
    Instance Id: d7e2cfde-2371-4427-8e6d-09b10beb04a1
       Crash Id: 8f231e6e-9afb-4cf7-90d9-5357ebb2e4cf
    Build stamp: 55e9595a94b6d3e7b784228f4a5253e5367473986e2ebc475dd669476db8fd11
   Distribution: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
     Processors: 8
   Total Memory: 16618315776 bytes
      Timestamp: Sat May  7 22:05:17 2022
Capturing a dump of 18822
Successfully captured dump: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.5_7_2022_22_5_17.18822
Executing: /opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh with parameters
     handle-crash.sh
     /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
     18822
     /opt/mssql/bin
     /var/opt/mssql/log/
     
     d7e2cfde-2371-4427-8e6d-09b10beb04a1
     8f231e6e-9afb-4cf7-90d9-5357ebb2e4cf
     
     /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.5_7_2022_22_5_17.18822

Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Capturing core dump and information to /var/opt/mssql/log...
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
/usr/bin/tail: cannot open '/var/log/syslog' for reading: Permission denied
Sat May  7 10:05:19 PM +06 2022 Capturing program information
Dump already generated: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.5_7_2022_22_5_17.18822, moving to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.18822.temp/core.sqlservr.18822.gdmp
Moving logs to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.18822.temp/log/paldumper-debug.log
Sat May  7 10:05:20 PM +06 2022 Capturing program binaries
Sat May  7 10:05:24 PM +06 2022 Compressing the dump files
Core dump and information are being compressed in the background. When
complete, they can be found in the following location:
  /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.05_07_2022_22_05_18.18822.tbz2
Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG
in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.
```

Both versions worked previously in 21.04 and earlier (according to my testing). Am I doing something wrong or does MS SQL Server is yet to roll out support for 22.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 has been out for only a few weeks and it is not [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15#supportedplatforms) (yet). 21.04 was/is not actually supported either.

Comment: You can also see this, as SQL Server isn't listed in the [Microsoft 22.04 repo](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/)

Comment: Considering that you are stating in the above that you have paid for an enterprise version of SQL Server, I would strongly suggest using an explicitly supported operating system (Pop OS, though based on Ubuntu, likely isn't supported, and non-LTS versions are not supported at all).

Comment: Yep it is apparent that 22.04 is not yet supported. @DavidBrowne-Microsoft where can I find your docker?

Comment: The link above had the instructions, @manchitro .

Comment: He meant "docker image" not "docker I made"

Comment: Add yourself to the `adm` group first. To view the file `/var/log/syslog` Seems that you should add the unixuser you were logged in as with `usermod -a -G adm manchitro`. Does the DB server have its own account? If so, add that user, too. Maybe this helps. Inferring this from reading the output you posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As many people pointed out MS SQL Server is yet not supported for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15#supportedplatforms) (thanks @Larnu for pointing it out)

However, I used a docker container to run MS SQL Server 2017 in Ubuntu 22.07. You can also run 2019 version I presume. Just download the 2019 image instead.

Guide here: [Quickstart: Run SQL Server container images with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017&preserve-view=true&pivots=cs1-bash)